# Erase nested map elements

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I have a map which looks like

```
typedef std::map<int, std::set<float>> innerMap;
typedef std::map<long, innerMap> outerMap;
```

I want to do following:
1. I want to erase inner map elements for a key of outer map.
2. Then I want to erase outer map key if it contains 0 inner map elements.

For first scenario, I have written code as:

```
outerMap mapA;
//assuming this map contain an element
//longx is key in outer element, intx is key of inner element
std::map<int, std::set<float>>::const_iterator innerIter = mapA[longx].begin();
while (innerIter != mapA[longx].end())
{
  if (innerIter->first == intx)
  {
    if (innerIter->second.size() == 0)
    {
      mapA[longx].erase(innerIter++);
    }
    break;
  }
  ++innerIter;
}
```

I have written this code in C++ but I wanna use C++11. Can we write this in a better way in C++11?

For second scenario, do I need to iterate again outer map and check its value elements or I can do it in existing code itself?

Comment: maybe you really need `std::multimap`?

Comment: Do you ever remove more than one element from innerMap? The code seems like it only ever removes a single element, I don't quite see why you would need a loop for this.

Comment: @Hcorg, thats a good point, I'll explore multimap for my requirements.

Comment: @bennofs, you are right, at a time, I'll remove one element only. But oncea set element from inner element is removed, I'll have to check if set is empty or not so that I can erase entire inner element.

Comment: @Nipun your code doesn't compile:

`test.cpp:14:45: error: no viable conversion from '_Rb_tree_const_iterator<pair<const int, std::set<float, std::less<float>, std::allocator<float> >>>' to '_Rb_tree_const_iterator<pair<const
      long, std::map<int, std::set<float, std::less<float>, std::allocator<float> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::set<float, std::less<float>, std::allocator<float>
      > > > >>>'`
  
In line: `std::map <long, innerMap>::const_iterator innerIter = mapA[longx].cbegin();`

Comment: The type annotation for innerIter is wrong: `mapA[longx].begin()` has type `innerMap::iterator`.

Comment: @bennofs, thanks for helping me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85416/discussion-between-bennofs-and-nipun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks way too complicated to me. The following should do the same, no need to use fancy C++11 features:

```
outerMap mapA;

// Lookup iterator for element of outerMap.
outerMap::iterator const outerIter = mapA.find(longx);

// Lookup iterator for element of innerMap that should be checked.
innerMap::const_iterator const innerIter = outerIter->second.find(intx);

// Check if element of innerMap should be erased and erase it if yes.
if(innerIter != outerIter->second.end() && innerIter->second.size() == 0) {
  outerIter->second.erase(innerIter);
}

// Erase element of outer map is inner map is now empty:
// This should do scenario 2
if(outerIter->second.size() == 0) {
  mapA.erase(outerIter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you do currently (in C++11):

```
auto& inner = mapA[longx];
const auto it = inner.find(intx);
if (it != inner.end() && it->second.size() == 0) {
    inner.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: In second line, it shoud be find(intx), not find(it.x). its a typo.

Comment: Also, this code does not do the same as the code in the question: the code in the question removes the element from `inner`, not from `mapA`. (It calls `mapA[longx].erase(innerIter++)`). However, it is hard to guess what the code in the question should really do, since it contains compile errors.

Comment: @bennofs: fixed to be as code and not as description.